# How can find which object cause null object reference in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have this error in my flash application and con not find error source? Is it possible find which object cause this error with flash debugger?

```
    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Reading2mergedlayers_fla::MainTimeline/hideTimer2()
    at Reading2mergedlayers_fla::MainTimeline/frame37()
    at flash.display::MovieClip/prevFrame()
    at Reading2mergedlayers_fla::MainTimeline/back32()
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the code from Flash Builder (with your source hooked up in some sort of Project--which kind will depend on what you have). The debugger should stop at the line with the error, and you can see which variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you permit debugging in the flash settings, Flash will print the line number at which the error occurred in the console. This makes it much easier to figure out which object is causing problems. You can enable this by performing the following steps:

> With the FLA file open, select File > Publish Settings.
>
> In the Publish Settings dialog box, click the Flash tab (CS5) or Flash
>   category (CS5.5).
>
> Select Permit Debugging.

[See this article](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/debugging-actionscript-3-0.html) for more information.